# Which game engine is compatiable with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Silverlight?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I would like to use a game engine with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Flat Red Ball only seems to work with Visual Studio 2008 or express edition.

You will receive "You can't add a reference to as it was not built against FlatRedBall.dll the silverlight runtime" when you try to add this reference to a Silverlight Navigation Application.

Which game engine is compatiable with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Silverlight, if not Flat Red Ball?

**EDIT**

I found the solution. It is compatiable. You just need to use the right "template" and with a bit of hacking, I now have the Flat Silver Ball "template" working in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Please update the question with more details like the fact that you're specifically looking for a Silverlight or other browser engine.

Comment: It's already mentioned twice in there that I'm looking for a silverlight compatiable solution

Comment: Three times silverlight is mentioned now

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Read widely to find your answer and hack around with the Flat Silver Ball "template".

First, download the Flat Silver Ball "template" from here: [FlatSilverBallTemplate.zip](http://www.flatredball.com/content/FrbXnaTemplates/2011/April/ZippedTemplates/FlatSilverBallTemplate.zip)

**CAUTION**: This is not exactly a VS2010 template but just a solution file containing a couple of projects. So, do not try to install it like a *real* template. This can cause you no end of pain.

Second, ensure that:

1) You unblock the three library files
2) Comment out the line `FlatRedBall.Debugging.Debugger.DestroyText();`

After that, we are ready to use Flat Silver Ball with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Silverlight.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to the statements in your question, [Flat Red Ball](http://www.flatredball.com) uses XNA 4 and therefore ***does*** work with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: 2010 version is done and works, they've released a game with XNA4. However, the content processors aren't ported yet so only file-based content loading works in XNA4/VS2010 with FRB (though they state this is on the way).

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, FlatRedBall XNA4 only works in Visual Studio 2010 by design and FlatRedBall XNA3.1 only works in Visual Studio 2008 - just add the right version DLLs. I have no problem developing with FlatRedBall XNA4 in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - it works just fine. FlatSilverBall is a different beast altogether but as it has no dependency on XNA the 2008 template should convert just fine to 2010. My guess is you need to start a FlatSilverBall project from their tempaltes - not a Silverlight Navigation Application?

Comment: @Carnotaurus: I don't think that you fully understand the spirit of this site or how to use it best to serve you. I'm trying to help you answer your question, and I don't know if you mean to, but to me it seems like you're a little rude for someone seeking free help from professionals. I don't have extensive experience with Flat Red Ball, but building games in XNA (with VS2010) is my primary source of income, and I've been programming for 15 years. I like to think that at least I have "a clue". You should consider why users have downvoted your question to -6 and your answer to -2!

Answer (score 1):

Unity3D
UDK using nFringe
XNA (framework, not engine)
Silverlight (2D framework, not engine)
Torque 3D

And pretty much every open source C/C++ engine ever

Support for debugging does vary among the engines.

Comment: Agreed, maybe note that there are a ton of engines built on XNA since that could be the first choice given this type of question

Comment: if your requirement is to run in a browser, then Phykocyber's answer of unity is the best choice for 3d. silverlight for 2d

Comment: You can write all your Unity scripts using VS2010 just fine.